# Mongoid: How to reference parent object attributes from a child in N-to-N relationship

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm totally new to mongoid. Is there any options or something in class relationship definition to enable this?

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type:String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :members
end

class Member
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bands
end

andy = Member.new(name: 'Andy Bell')

ride = Band.new(name: 'Ride')
ride.members << andy
oasis = Band.new(name: 'Oasis')
oasis.members << andy

andy.bands #=> returns: [] (empty array)
andy.band_ids #=> returns: [BSON::ObjectId('53586a786d6163870c030000'), BSON::ObjectId('53586a786d6163870c040000')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but reading from [the docs here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) there is the reload method, does that help?:

> If you are using a default scope on a model that is part of a relation
>   like a has_many, has_and_belongs_to_many, or embeds_many, you must
>   reload the relation to have scoping reapplied. This is important to
>   note if you change a value of a document in the relation that would
>   affect its visibility within the scoped relation.

```
class Label
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :bands
end

class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :active, default: true
  embedded_in :label
  default_scoped where(active: true)
end

label.bands.push(band)
label.bands #=> [ band ]
band.update_attribute(:active, false)
label.bands #=> [ band ] Must reload.
label.reload.bands #=> []
```